# How to get the last inserted array key in mongodb using php?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a collection

```
[_id] => 1
    [user_id] => 2
    [work_details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [login_date] => 2015-12-22
                    [login_time] => 16:40:00
                    [log_out_time] => 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [login_date] => 2015-12-23
                    [login_time] => 11:40:00
                    [log_out_time] => 
                )

        )
```

for updating i am using the following query

```
 $collect->update(array("user_id"=>(int)$user_id,"work_details.0.login_date"=>'2015-12-22'),array('$push' => array("work_details.0.log_out_time" =>$logout_time)));
```

so for updating the last record I need to know last key value

I need to update the log_out_time for work_details[1].How to get the last inserted array key in mongodb using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) gives you the value of the last element of the array. It also move's the internal pointer for the array to the end so that when you use...

[key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) it will give you the key for that same element.

So:

```
$myarray = array(
   'a' => 'hello'
   7 => 'world'
   2 => '!!!'
)

$last = end($myarray); // $last = '!!!'
$lastKey = key($myarray); // $lastKey = 2
```

Note that key() would NOT return the last key if you hadn't first used end().

Comment: how to implement this in mongodb

Comment: You said *'so for updating the last record I need to know last key value '* you use this method on your work_details array to get it's last key. It appears you already have the rest of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
<?php

    $work_details = Array        (
           0 => Array
                (
                    'login_date' => '2015-12-22',
                    'login_time' => '16:40:00',
                    'log_out_time' => '',
                ),
            1 => Array
                (
                    'login_date' => '2015-12-23',
                    'login_time' => '11:40:00',
                    'log_out_time' => '', 
                )

        );

    //get last item of an array
    $last_item = end($work_details);

    //set pointer to fist item
    reset($work_details);

    $last_item_key = null;

    //compare value of last item with all values of an array, if found equal, return that key
    foreach($work_details as $key => $value) {

        if($value === $last_item) {
            $last_item_key = $key;
            break;    
        }

    }

    echo $last_item_key;


?>
```

Comment: After running `$last_item = end($work_details);` just use `$last_item_key = key($work_details)`.  No need to loop and search. See my answer